# How to construct a natural isomorphism of hom-sets from an adjunction of functors

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $F: C \rightarrow D,\ G: D \rightarrow C$ be an adjunction of functors. My goal is to construct an isomorphism

$$Hom_D(F(x), y) \simeq Hom_C(x, G(y))$$

So given a morphism $f(x): F(x)\rightarrow y$, I can form a morphism $g: x \rightarrow G(y)$ by

$$G(f)\circ e_x: x \rightarrow GF(x) \rightarrow G(y)$$

Conversely, given $g: x \rightarrow G(y)$, I can form some $f': F(x) \rightarrow y$, by

$$\epsilon_y \circ F(g): F(x) \rightarrow F(G(y)) \rightarrow y$$

I feel to see why $f = f'$, ie why these two mappings of morphisms I defined are inverses of each other. I'm looking for an answer that carefully spells out why this is the case.

Comment: what is your definition of adjunction of functors?

Comment: This: https://imgur.com/ccY5kZQ, @PraphullaKoushik

Comment: Fine.. It is not clear what you have tried to do in the question... Given an arrow $F(x)\rightarrow y$, you are supposed to associate an arrow $x\rightarrow G(y)$.... Similarly, given an arrow $x\rightarrow G(y)$ you are supposed to associate an arrow $F(x)\rightarrow y$.. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, thank you for pointing this out, there was a small typo in my initial post that I have just corrected now. Could you have another look?

Comment: @gen What is your definition for an adjunction?